# Show number of elements in multiple sets in a chart

Tags: tableau-api

I create about 10 sets using my tableau data. I want to show the number of elements in all sets in a chart, for example, bubble chart, or bar chart. When I move a single set to the sheet and select the number of records and filter the in elements I can see the number of elements in the set, however, I want to simultaneously see the number of records in multiple sets.

When I try to put multiple sets to a for example bubble chart, Tableau creates one single bubble instead of multiple bubbles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets are very useful, but may not be the best approach when you have a very large number of similar groupings to compare side by side when you are using them as dimensions.

Remember the purpose of dimensions is to partition your data into non overlapping blocks prior to aggregating measures. Since a data row may belong to multiple sets, using sets as dimensions doesn't fit the particular application you describe. (but using sets as filters or building blocks for calculations might)

So here is one approach that will give you some flexibility. Define a calculated field for each set to return 1 if the record is in set 1, null otherwise (One way to think of sets is as a boolean function)

**Number of Set 1 Records**

```
if [Set_1] then 1 end
```

Then you you can use SUM([Number of Set 1 Records]) as a measure as desired. You can use Measure Values to display multiple measures together.

This way your set definitions are used for calculating your measures, but not for partitioning the data rows.

If your sets are completely defined by a condition, and this is the only way you use them, you could simplify by using the condition directly in the calculated fields above and not creating the corresponding sets.

Comment: Hi, Alex can you please upvote the question. I have issues related to the number of questions with 0 votes. This problem causes me not entering new questions.

Comment: I already upvoted the question long ago. I guess someone else must have downvoted it.

Comment: Thank you Alex for the response :)